# Update a Realtime Database node to be null instead of deleting it

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Realtime Database and would like to empty a node instead of deleting it completely even if it has no children. Whether I use update() with null or straight-up remove() or even just manually delete all the children of a node, I'd like for the head node to still exist and just be empty afterwards.
Example:

```
--headNode
  --key1
    --properties of object1
  --key2
    --properties of object2
```

If I delete just key2, then headNode and key1 will remain. But if I try to remove or update(null) key 1, then my entire headNode is also automatically deleted since it's now empty. I'd like for it to just exist on its own.

I've tried deleting or updating the last remaining child object with null, but that ends up deleting the whole head node as well since it's now totally empty. I know it's possible to have an empty node, but is there a way to delete all its children without the head node disappearing on its own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to have a node without a value in the Firebase Realtime Database. Once you write a `null` value, the database deletes the node - and any parent nodes that have become empty due to the operation.

The common workaround for your use-case is to store a dummy value that your code then recognizes, similar to how you'd handle the `null` if that was allowed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm able to get an 'empty' node if I add a new node with just a key; it then shows up in the database as myEmptyNode: "" and I can push new nodes to it from there. I was wondering if there's a way to get it back to just being "" after removing all the nodes, but it looks like I may have to manually check to see if I'm at the last node and 'reset' from there.

Comment: That's not an empty node, but a node with an empty string as its value. --- And nope, there is nothing built in for it to revert back to that default value automatically. You'll have to do that from your application code.